# nDepend querying direct indirect methods for all methods in an assembly

Tags: cql, ndepend

I am trying to retrieve all direct indirect method calls for all methods in an assembly using the CQL provided by nDepend.
Issue is I am not able to iterate through all methods inside a assembly to get this info.

The DepthOfIsUsedBy only allows a string type and not a collection of strings.

Is there a way t get this info for all methods inside an assembly?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the method [DepthOfIsUsing()](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.Reserved.CQLinq.ExtensionMethodsCQLinqDependency~DepthOfIsUsing.html) instead of [DepthOfIsUsedBy()](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.Reserved.CQLinq.ExtensionMethodsCQLinqDependency~DepthOfIsUsedBy.html) :o)

```
from m in Assemblies.WithNameNotIn("nunit.uikit").ChildMethods() 
let depth0 = m.DepthOfIsUsing("nunit.uikit")
where depth0  >= 0 orderby depth0
select new { m, depth0 }
```

This query has been generated through the menu below. (Btw a more sophisticated solution could be elaborated with the magic method [FillIterative()](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ExtensionMethodsHelpers~FillIterative.html), but it is not necessary here).

[image]

---

Taking account the comment of Prasad, what about trying this query that list all direct & indirect callers from A, for each method of B:

```
from m in Assemblies.WithNameIn("AsmB").ChildMethods()
where m.IsPubliclyVisible // Optimization
let indirectcallers = m.MethodsCallingMe
                      .FillIterative(
                          callers => callers.SelectMany(m1 => m1.MethodsCallingMe))
                      .DefinitionDomain
                      .Where(m1 => m1.ParentAssembly.Name == "AsmA")
                      .ToArray()  // Avoid double enumeration
where indirectcallers.Length > 0
orderby indirectcallers.Length descending
select new { m, indirectcallers }
```

Comment: Patrick Thanks for that logic...but again the constraint is I am trying to do it for all methods inside assembly a to know what each method inside assembly a is calling method per se in assembly b...in other words how to make this recursive for all methods...also the result should be a mapping between method a in assembly a calling method(s) in assembly b.

Comment: Patrick..thanks for the update..I will try this query and let you know how it goes..! Thanks!